# In how many ways can the rooks be arranged?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, contest-math

> In how many ways can 9 black and 9 white rooks be placed on a 6 × 6 chess
>   board, so that no white rook can capture a black one?
>   A rook can capture another piece if it is in the same rank (row) or the same
>   file (column) as the other piece, with no other pieces between the two.

This is terribly hard. I literally dont understand.

The solution says you cant have one color occupy more than 3 rows, but it clearly can! How should I do this?

Comment: Consider that you have more rooks of each color then there is rows. This shows multiple rooks have to be on a row. no row can contain rooks of different colors. The same goes for columns. How few rows and columns can you possibly occupy with 9 rooks? How many non-threatened spaces are there if you put one color of rooks in more then 3 rows? Don't forget you can't get all rooks in one column.

Comment: @DRF, why cant row contain different colored rooks?

Comment: There are more white rooks than rows, thus at least two columns contain white rooks. So suppose at least 4 rows contain white rooks. That leaves 2 rows for the black rooks. But the black rooks cannot go in the same columns as the white rooks, thus there are at least 4 squares in those 2 rows where the black rooks cannot go. This leaves 8 squares available for the black rooks, which isn't enough. So no, one color cannot occupy more than 3 rows.

Comment: @Ama Because then a white rook would be able to capture a black rook.

Comment: @JackM, cant the black rooks be at column(6), row 4?

Comment: @Ama No - there's a white row in row 4, and it would threaten the black rook (and vice versa).

Comment: Yes, but there is SPACE between them?

Comment: @Ama what does that have to do with anything? Rooks can take any piece that is in the same row/column with no intervening PIECES not SPACES.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one color (say, black) in 4 different rows, it means that you will need to distribute the white rooks in only 2 rows, otherwise they could be captured. If you have 9 rooks to distribute on only 2 rows, you will FOR SURE occupy $\lceil 9/2 \rceil = 5$ different columns. Finally, if you have your black rooks placed in 4 different rows, the least number of columns they will occupy are $\lceil 9/4 \rceil = 3$, so your rooks always can capture each other in this scenario.

On the other hand, if a color appears in 5 rows, it is trivial that you will get rooks in capturing positions. I hope this tip helps to derive the result.